# Are there lightbulb base adapters available?

Tags: light-fixture

I've got an intermediate screw base light bulb that I want to replace (as it's burned out).  However, going around to local stores they only have the correct size & wattage of bulb available in either medium base screw or some weird looking 2 prong thing that I've never seen before.  Since adapting medium down to intermediate would probably take up too much space, are there 2 prong to intermediate base adapters available anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are definitely available though specifics as to where to buy them are generally considered off-topic for this site.

Here's a [GU10-WHIP flexible socket adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0052Z937O):

[image: GU10]

Or [here's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004KOKEVC) a more traditional Bi-Pin to Standard Base adapter:

[image: BiPinAdapter]

Comment: Asking if something exists, is usually a loophole way of asking a "shop for me" type question.  Answers will almost certainly contain links to products on Amazon.

Comment: Maybe I should have phrased it as "what do they call those goofy 2 pin connectors"?  I've been shopping for them, but had no luck coming up with search terms that found anything useful.  :-)

Comment: Generically they are Bi-Pin/two pin.  Actual bulb types are usually GU10, MR16

Comment: I was able to snag a GE 4.5w GU10 based bulb with a form factor similar to a PAR-14 (fixture originally had R-14, but PAR works for my application too) at my local Andersons store.  Then I found single piece E17 intermediate screw base to GU10 adapters at Bulborama.  Bulb projects a little beyond the shield with all the added length, but with a PAR beamwidth it works out great!  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for GU24 bulbs

Relevant question: 
[Are standard light bulb bases being phased out?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/are-standard-light-bulb-bases-being-phased-out)

If so, a typical [Edison Screw Bulb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison_screw) *may* work fine but you're better off buying the bulb intended for the ballast.